# Application Factory Pattern: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shell_context_processor'

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am trying to cast my Flask app into a App Factory Pattern, but I got stuck on the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/flask", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 848, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 305, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 330, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 388, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/chrdina/python/werda/werda.py", line 7, in <module>
    @app.shell_context_processor
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shell_context_processor'
```

I tried to find out where the AttributeError happens, but I'm totally stuck. I don't unterstand where the mentioned tuple is located in my code. I tried deleting the shell_context_processor part, but then the app seems to not know it's an app at all and throws this `"Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "werda". Use "FLASK_APP=werda:name to specify one.")`.

If I then try to export `FLASK_APP` again (it's already set in my `.flaskenv`) nothing changes.

I define the shell_context_processor in my `werda.py` (which is my app) in the top level of my directory.

**werda.py**:

```
from app import create_app, db
from app.models import User, Role, Employee, Language, Employee_Languages, Attendance, AttendanceArchive

app = create_app()

@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return {'db': db, 'User': User, 'Role': Role, 'Employee':Employee, 'Language':Language, 'Employee_Languages':Employee_Languages, 'Attendance':Attendance, 'AttendanceArchive':AttendanceArchive}
```

****init**.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore
from flask_mail import Mail
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler, RotatingFileHandler
import os
from config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
bootstrap = Bootstrap()
from app.models import User, Role
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security()
mail = Mail()
admin = Admin()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app=Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    from app.models import User, Role
    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    security.init_app(app, user_datastore)
    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)


    app.config['FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH'] = 'cerulean'

    from app.errors import bp as errors_bp
    app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)

    from app.main import bp as main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

    admin = Admin(app, name='werda', template_mode='bootstrap3')

    #send errors via mail:
    if not app.debug:
        if app.config['MAIL_SERVER']:
            auth = None
            if app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] or app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']:
                auth = (app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'], app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'])
            secure = None
            if app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']:
                secure = ()
            mail_handler = SMTPHandler(
                mailhost=(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'], app.config['MAIL_PORT']),
                fromaddr='no-reply@' + app.config['MAIL_SERVER'],
                toaddrs=app.config['ADMINS'], subject='werda Failure',
                credentials=auth, secure=secure)
            mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
            app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
        #save errors to log file:
        if not os.path.exists('logs'):
            os.mkdir('logs')
        file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/werda.log', maxBytes=10240,
                                        backupCount=10)
        file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        app.logger.info('werda startup')

    return app, admin

from app import models
```

**Directory Structure**

```
.
├── app
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── errors
│   │   ├── handlers.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── routes.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── addnextweek.html
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── errors
│       │   ├── 403.html
│       │   ├── 404.html
│       │   └── 500.html
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── movetoarchive.html
│       ├── nextweek.html
│       ├── now.html
│       ├── russ.html
│       ├── security
│       │   ├── login_user.html
│       │   └── register_user.html
│       ├── thisweek.html
│       ├── thisweek_working.html
│       └── today.html
├── app.db
├── config.py
├── libc6_2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1_amd64.deb
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── werda.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!
I return'ed app and admin in create_app(), which caused the problem. And it seems that's also where the mysterious Tuple was situated.
If create_app() only return's app my app starts as it should. Now to work out how to run flask-admin correctly.
Corrected code for now:
**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore
from flask_mail import Mail
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler, RotatingFileHandler
import os
from config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
bootstrap = Bootstrap()
from app.models import User, Role
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security()
mail = Mail()
admin = Admin()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app=Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    from app.models import User, Role
    user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
    security.init_app(app, user_datastore)
    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)


    app.config['FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH'] = 'cerulean'

    from app.errors import bp as errors_bp
    app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)

    from app.main import bp as main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

    admin = Admin(app, name='werda', template_mode='bootstrap3')

    #send errors via mail:
    if not app.debug:
        if app.config['MAIL_SERVER']:
            auth = None
            if app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] or app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']:
                auth = (app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'], app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'])
            secure = None
            if app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']:
                secure = ()
            mail_handler = SMTPHandler(
                mailhost=(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'], app.config['MAIL_PORT']),
                fromaddr='no-reply@' + app.config['MAIL_SERVER'],
                toaddrs=app.config['ADMINS'], subject='werda Failure',
                credentials=auth, secure=secure)
            mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
            app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
        #save errors to log file:
        if not os.path.exists('logs'):
            os.mkdir('logs')
        file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/werda.log', maxBytes=10240,
                                        backupCount=10)
        file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        app.logger.info('werda startup')

    return app #deleted admin here

from app import models
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use the `init_app()` function in your factory function. You also should modify your `app.config.from_object(Config)` to `app.config.from_object(class_config)`

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore
from flask_mail import Mail
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler, RotatingFileHandler
import os
from config import Config
from app.models import User, Role #<-----------repositioned



db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
bootstrap = Bootstrap()
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore() #<-------------modified
security = Security()
mail = Mail()
admin = Admin()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app=Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(class_config) #<------modified

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)    
    user_datastore.init_app = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(app, db, User, Role) #<-------modified
    security.init_app(app, user_datastore)
    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)


    app.config['FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH'] = 'cerulean'

    from app.errors import bp as errors_bp
    app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)

    from app.main import bp as main_bp
    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

    admin = Admin(app, name='werda', template_mode='bootstrap3')
    




    #send errors via mail:
    if not app.debug:
        if app.config['MAIL_SERVER']:
            auth = None
            if app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] or app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']:
                auth = (app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'], app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'])
            secure = None
            if app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']:
                secure = ()
            mail_handler = SMTPHandler(
                mailhost=(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'], app.config['MAIL_PORT']),
                fromaddr='no-reply@' + app.config['MAIL_SERVER'],
                toaddrs=app.config['ADMINS'], subject='werda Failure',
                credentials=auth, secure=secure)
            mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
            app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
        #save errors to log file:
        if not os.path.exists('logs'):
            os.mkdir('logs')
        file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/werda.log', maxBytes=10240,
                                        backupCount=10)
        file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        app.logger.info('werda startup')

    

    return app, admin

from app import models
```

Comment: Thanks for your input!
Now I get the following error:
`
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/chrdina/python/werda/werda.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import create_app, db
  File "/home/chrdina/python/werda/app/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from app.models import User, Role
  File "/home/chrdina/python/werda/app/models.py", line 9, in <module>
    from app import db
ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'app' (/home/chrdina/python/werda/app/__init__.py)
`
Any idea?